# Differences between different types of functions in R

Tags: r, function

I would appreciate help understanding the main differences between several types of functions in R.

I'm somewhat overwhelmed among the definitions of different types of functions and it has become somewhat difficult to understand how different types of functions might relate to each other.

Specifically, I'm confused about the relationships and differences between the following types of functions:

1. **Either Generic or Method**: based on the class of the input argument(s), generic functions by using Method Dispatch call an appropriate method function.
2. **Invisible vs. Visible**
3. **Primitive vs. Internal**

I'm confused about how these different types of functions relate to each other (if at all) and what the various differences and overlaps are between them.

Comment: I _radically_ edited your question, because it was going to be closed with minutes, if not seconds. It still might be too broad, but at least it's got a fighting shot now.

Comment: I appreciate it, Joran. You know what, having some members like you has made me more and more interested in SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some documentation about primitive vs internal: http://www.biosino.org/R/R-doc/R-ints/_002eInternal-vs-_002ePrimitive.html

Generics are generic functions that can be applied to a class object.  Each class is written with specific methods that are then set as generic.  So you can see the specific methods associated with a generic call with the "methods" function:

```
methods(print)
```

This will list all the methods associated with the generic "print".
Alternatively you can see all the generics that a given class has with this call

```
methods(,"lm")
```

Where lm is the class linear model.
Here's an example:

```
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- 1 + .4*x + rnorm(100,0,.1)
mod1 <- lm(y~x)
print(mod1)
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
       1.002        0.378  

print.lm(mod1)
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
       1.002        0.378
```

Both the print(mod1) (the generic call) and print.lm(mod1) (the method call to the class) do the same thing.  Why does R do this?  I don't really know, but that's the difference between method and generic as I understand it.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. The reason that you can call print.lm() directly is because this method function is visible and can be called directly by the user. However, in some other functions that are not visible like group functions of Math, Summary and Ops, you cannot call them or even their method functions directly. They can only be called through their components.

Comment: That's true.  You can see those that are visible or invisible in the methods(print) call.  When the list is displayed, they're printed with a * next to them.